# can not specify config file in CMD for redis in the dockerfile

Tags: docker, redis

I have  Dockerfile for running redis with my own config file,

```
FROM redis:latest

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY ./redis.conf /usr/app


CMD ["redis-server","/usr/app/redis.conf"]
```

the only thing diff in the file from the standard redis.conf file is that I am binding server to the 0.0.0.0 address, like so

```
# By default, if no "bind" configuration directive is specified, Redis listens
# for connections from all the network interfaces available on the server.
# It is possible to listen to just one or multiple selected interfaces using
# the "bind" configuration directive, followed by one or more IP addresses.
# Examples:
#
# bind 192.168.1.100 10.0.0.1
bind 0.0.0.0
```

when I try to run the image created from this Dockerfile, it does not produce any container

```
[13:39:37]:~/desktop/xxx: docker run -v /var:/var bm-redis
[13:40:09]:~/desktop/xxx: docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

when I try to look at the logs for the container name I specified, there is nothing

the funny thing is, if I run docker in the interactive mode like so, everything works

```
[13:48:17]:~/desktop/xxx: docker run -it --network=host -v /var:/var bm-redis bash
root@satyen-laptop-x15:/usr/app# redis-server /usr/app/redis.conf 
root@satyen-laptop-x15:/usr/app# tail /usr/app/redis-server.log 
              `-.__.-'                                               

9:M 16 Jul 2020 20:48:39.212 # Server initialized
9:M 16 Jul 2020 20:48:39.212 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
9:M 16 Jul 2020 20:48:39.212 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
9:M 16 Jul 2020 20:48:39.213 * Loading RDB produced by version 5.0.7
9:M 16 Jul 2020 20:48:39.213 * RDB age 86443 seconds
9:M 16 Jul 2020 20:48:39.213 * RDB memory usage when created 0.76 Mb
9:M 16 Jul 2020 20:48:39.213 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
9:M 16 Jul 2020 20:48:39.213 * Ready to accept connections
```

any idea about what am I doing wrong??

some other things I have tried, that did not provide any help in this

- restarted docker service
- looked at the docker daemon log...no clue there
- tried to use ENTRYPOINT instead of CMD to start the server

Comment: After you run `redis-server`, do you control-C stop it, or do you immediately get a shell prompt back?  If you immediately get a shell prompt back, you need an option to start it as a foreground process and not a daemon.

Comment: (As you've described the setup – it's identical to the Docker Hub `redis` image, except it listens on all interfaces – I don't think you need a custom image or even to change the config file, I'd expect the standard `redis` image to do what you need.)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by after starting redis-server... when I run redis-server in the interactive docker container, it runs in the background (i.e. I do get the prompt back). The server is up and running and I can connect to it from shells outside the docker container using redis-cli

Comment: the point of having a custom config file is that I need to make it part of a docker-compose setup, in which case I do need to bind to something other than localhost, so that other services in docker-compose can connect to it.

Comment: Please try your `docker-compose` setup with the stock `redis` image.  It should be set up correctly for this.

Comment: does that mean that redis image in docker-compose will detect the environment and bind to IP of the container and not to localhost??

Comment: Pretty much every standard Docker image knows that it needs to bind to 0.0.0.0.